# New Chrome Release SVG Sprites not showing via background / background-size / background position

Tags: google-chrome, svg

Hello I have been trying to fix this issue all day. With Chrome's latest release

> Version 53.0.2785.116 m

The svg sprites I had been using no longer appear. They appear in their correct positions in firefox and ie with no issues.

I looked at the release notes and could find nothing mentioning SVG. I really don't know how to remedy this problem since they show on all other browsers. Does any one have any clue?

Here is the some code I'm using for reference

```
&.ico-nav {
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
border: 2px solid @eia_green;
border-radius: 100%;
float: left;
margin: 0 15px 15px 0;
background: url(../images/global-nav-icons.svg) no-repeat;
background-size: 1700% 1700%;

/*Sources and Uses Menu*/
&.petro {
  background-position: -20px -225px;
}

&.natural {
  background-position: -20px -330px;
}

&.elec {
  background-position: -20px -430px;
}

&.con {
  background-position: -20px -530px;
}

&.coal {
  background-position: -20px -635px;
}

&.renew {
  background-position: -20px -735px;
}
```

I also have used the `symbol` and `defs` method for calling SVG inline and that has not worked either.

I have played around with dimensions and have gotten a icon to show but not with out truncating the sprite itself which has about 80 icons in total on it.

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT-----------------------------!**

This issue appears to be related to SVG and border radius. My SVGs look normal on Chrome Canary (Beta) and hopefully the change is coming down the pipeline.

Here is a chromium bug that was related to my issue so the devs at Chrome are aware!

Hope this helps anyone experiencing anything similar.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=643623

Comment: Contact Philip Rogers at chrome pdr@google.com . He should be able to help.

Comment: @FrancisHemsher thank you I have reached out and filed a bug. Have you experienced this issue as well?

Comment: Not yet, but glad you found it.

Comment: @FrancisHemsher For what its worth my issue is resolved in Chrome Canary (meaning the sprites show as they were before without any code mods) hopefully they get the change pushed up in the stable release soon.